# Создание всплывающего окна с произвольным содержимым

Tags: java, android

С помощью каких средств лучше создать [подобное](https://material.google.com/motion/material-motion.html#material-motion-how-does-material-move) всплывающее окно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрел уроки по `AlertDialog`, но не думаю, что это подходит. То, что я вижу на картинке, видимо в сухом остатке просто какой-то анимированный Layout фиксированных размеров, куда можно пихать всё, что угодно. Как правильно создать подобное окно?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: вы можете запихнуть в AlertDialog диалог свой layout в котором будет то что вам нужно(В пределах разумного)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вы что? Создаете свою разметку с вашим белым квадратом и всем, что душе угодно, называете ее, например, `alert.xml`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:backgroynd="#FAFAFA"
android:elevation="5dp"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:text="Hello, AlertDialog!"
    android:id="@+id/ad_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Далее

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
View my_custom_view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert, null); //находим разметку
adb.setView(my_custom_view); //ставим ее в окно
TextView ad_tv = (TextView)my_custom_view.findViewById(R.id.ad_tv); //находим TextView
ad_tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
ad.show();
```

**Edit**

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
View my_custom_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert, null);
d.setContentView(my_custom_view);
TextView ad_tv = (TextView)my_custom_view.findViewById(R.id.ad_tv);
ad_tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
d.show();
```