# DrawerLayout cannot be cast to LinearLayout при вызове диалогового окна

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Этот вопрос является продолжением темы [Создание всплывающего окна с произвольным содержимым](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577334/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC). В том вопросе было предложено такое решение:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
View my_custom_view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert, null); //находим разметку
adb.setView(my_custom_view); //ставим ее в окно
TextView ad_tv = (TextView)my_custom_view.findViewById(R.id.ad_tv); //находим TextView
ad_tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
ad.show();
```

Я вызываю диалог с помощью `FloatingActionButton` и получаю такой Exception:

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
```

Исключение происходит во второй строке. Сразу вопрос: причём тут `DrawerLayout`? Тем более, я не кастовал его, я кастовал Linear.

В подобных вопросах (как [в этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939798/classcastexception-android-widget-framelayoutlayoutparams-to-android-support-v4/24560175#24560175)) говорилось, что это действительно имеет отношение к `DrawerLayout`, но такое решение не помогло:

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Прошу Вас не просто написать решение, а объяснить, что происходит.

Comment: Попробуйте каст убрать вообще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View my_custom_view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert, null);
```

Скорее всего в твоем layout`e корневым элементом является DrawerLayout, а ты его хочешь прикостовать к LinearLayout, поэтому и ругается. Сделай так:

```
View my_custom_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert, null);
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!